# Unable to get top n-records for a dataset using groupby and nlargest functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ARNH.png).

The data provided here include hospital-specific charges for the more than 3,000 U.S. hospitals that receive Medicare Inpatient Prospective Payment System (IPPS) payments for the top 100 most frequently billed discharges, paid under Medicare based on a rate per discharge using the Medicare Severity Diagnosis Related Group (MS-DRG) for Fiscal Year (FY) 2011.

I executed the following commands on the dataframe to obtain top two records in terms of Total Discharges:

```
dataframe_1 = dataframe.groupby('Provider Id').sum()
dataframe_1.nlargest(2,'Total Discharges')
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
-> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2396 
   2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'Total Discharges'
```

Any help on understanding of the error is welcome!

Comment: Do you want to n-largest of `total discharges` within the group? If not, you you need to run `dataframe.nlargest(2,'Total Discharges')` because `dataframe_1` is a grouped dataframe

Comment: Yes, I need the top n-records within the group. But, even dataframe.nlargest(2,'Total Discharges') throws the same error.

Comment: Check the dtype of 'Total Discharges' column in your dataframe. sum() only does calculations on numeric columns.

Comment: Please print the output of `dataframe_1.head()` after the first row.

Comment: @ScottBoston Hi, the dtype of 'Total Discharges' column is int64. So, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @omdv Hi, I am able to print the output of dataframe_1.head(). That would be simply return the top five(as per indexing) records in the dataset.

Comment: I understand that. Do you see the "Total Discharge" field there? What will happen if you run `dataframe_1.info()`? Do you see the "Total Discharge" there as well? The error is very simple - it just tells that there is no field like "Total Discharge" and the reason likely is that it was non-numeric field before grouping like Scott Boston mentioned. Also check that your column name is specified correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe_1 = dataframe.groupby('Provider Id', as_index=False).sum()
dataframe_1.nlargest(2,'Total Discharges')
```

VinceP had already stated the correct root cause